# IntelliJ 10 vs IntelliJ 11: code-completion

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ide, intellij-idea

Look at the images below. This happens a lot. For example, typing "pub" will show me classes from Flex 4.5, while I really want to type "public". IntelliJ 10 seems to work just fine. How can I change that to work in IntelliJ 11 as well? Any suggestions?

IntelliJ 10 - good
[image: IntelliJ 10]

IntelliJ 11 - bad
[image: IntelliJ 11]

Comment: I've used FlashDevelop and it lacks a lot of features I really like in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Sorry not to talk about your problem but I'm curious about what IntelliJ brings to Flash development that FD hasn't.

Comment: Major features I use: multi-project, integrated svn with changelists, integrated support for bug trackers, detailed shorcuts for every single thing you may ask like move the cursor left, context views where you can save opened files and windows for a project and restore them when you open that project... Now please, answer my question about intellij since I'm not interested in FD anymore.

Comment: You could look through [the bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) to see if anyone else had similar issues, or [report a new issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA#newissue=yes). They are very helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @Radu. I'll do that now.

Comment: Radu is right. We track our issue tracker and forum more attentively. Answered you at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84421

Comment: Issue is fixed and the fix will be included in the next version of IntelliJ IDEA. Source: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84421 Not sure how to mark this questions as answered/completed/closed since the whole conversation is in the comments.

Comment: @PlamenAndreev so answer your own question and mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue will be fixed in build 118.255. Link to the [Bug Issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84421)